# making a div constantly be window width using jquery width

Tags: jquery, width

I have a div that I'd like to always be the width of the browser window even when the user is resizing it.  I wanted to use jquery .width but I'm not sure how to set it up so it's always adjusting even when the user resizes their window.  I'm not sure whether to use the jquery .css with .width or whether a different way would be better.

Comment: in css you can set `width:100%`.  Is that not enough to solve your problem?

Comment: divs are width 100% by default. Can you just make it a direct child of the body tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $('div').width($(window).width());
});
```

Comment: if you set width to `$(window).width()` and there is `padding`, `margin`, or other positioning properties, it will extend off the page.  You'll have to make sure these things are accounted for if they exist.

Comment: @Scrimothy which padding and margin are you talking about? window width gets the width of the viewport relative to the browser, not the document.

Comment: padding/margin of the div itself

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate [jQuery outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) `outerWidth([addMarginBoolean])` method adds `border`, `padding`, and optionally `margin` into the normal `width` of an element.  If you foresee an issue with the width of the div going past the edge of the window, then you can try this.

```
function setWidth() {
  $('.width100').outerWidth($(window).width() - $('.width100').offset().left);
}
$(window).on('resize', setWidth); // resize div on window resize
setWidth();​ // resize div on page load
```

[Here's a fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/fVMdR/3/)